# calculating the line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

It is a simple line integral, but I haven't really grasped the idea yet.

$$
\mbox{Calculate the integral}\quad\int_{L}x^{2}\,y\,d\ell
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
L \equiv \left\{\,x^{2} + y^{2} = R^{2}\ \mid\  y\geq 0\,\right\}
$$
My attempt:

Form what is known above we get $y=\sqrt{\,R^{2} - x^{2}\,}$, $y \geq 0$, so
$0 \leq x \leq R$.

So the integral we have to calculate is
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{R}x^{2}\,\sqrt{\,R^{2} - x^{2}\,}\,\,\mathrm{d}x$.

But I got stuck here.  I also tried polar coordinates but got a wrong result.
Any ideas ?.

Comment: Can you use polar coordinates?

Comment: You were doing it well. The integral is really simple in cartesian coordinates: $$\int_{-R}^RRx^2dx$$

Comment: @RafaBudría I will try that thank you

Comment: Because $y\gt0$, so is, you are integrating for half a circumference. I think it is very interesting for you to try to use cartesian. The hard point is calculate the line element $dl=\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$ with $y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ as you calculated.

Comment: @thank I got it know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar coordinates facilitates the evaluation of the line integral.  We can write $x=R\cos(\phi)$, $y=R\sin(\phi)$, and $d\ell =R\,d\phi$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_L x^2y\,d\ell &= \int_0^{\pi} R^4 \cos^2(\phi)\sin(\phi)\,d\phi\\\\
&=R^4\left.\left(-\frac13 \cos^3(\phi)\right)\right|_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\pi}\\\\
&=\frac23R^4
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you! what I did wrong was i did a double integral on angle and R. why did you choose to limit angle between 0 and $\pi$?

Comment: $\theta$ is known as the angle measured from the positive x-axis in a counter clockwise direction and given $y \geq o$ So, mark choose $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ From $\pi$ to 2 $\pi$ we would have the negative y.

Comment: @segevp You're welcome.  My pleasure.  As Crazy explained, since $y\ge 0$, then $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (from where you are stuck):

$$\int x^2 \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}dx = \int \left((x^2 - R^2) + R^2\right)\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}dx $$

$$ = \int \left(x^2 - R^2\right) \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}dx +\int R^2 \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}dx =$$

$$ = -\int  (R^2 - x^2)^{3/2}dx + \int R^2 \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}dx $$

and these integrals can be solved using the substitution $x = \sin(t), dx = \cos(t)dt$

Note that Mark Viola's answer is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course apply the line integral's definition: the half circle can be parametrized as $\gamma(t)=(R \cos(t), R \sin(t))$, with $t \in [0,\pi]$, so the derived vector is $\gamma'(t)=(-R \sin(t),R \cos(t))$. Then $f(x,y)=x^2y$
$$
\int_{\gamma} f(x(t),y(t)) ||\gamma' (t)|| dt=
$$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} R^3 \cos^2(t) \sin (t) \sqrt{R^2 \sin^2(t) + R^2 \cos^2(t)} dt = 
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} R^4 \cos^2 (t) \sin (t) dt
$$
from now on the computation are the same as in Mark Viola's answer.